# Cakephp form ,but returning the validaation errors in ajax

Tags: ajax, cakephp

I have created a cakephp form and created a model as well.I have submitted the form in Cake, but I want to return the error in ajax.

Please assist.

Comment: How to assit you if we don't see any piece of code?

Comment: thanks for the acknowledement.
I fixed it.